# Fuction has an array inside, gives back error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula that works fine when hardcoded but gives me error 1004 when I put it in code. I think it's because I am using an array inside the formula. I tried .FormulaArray but it still returns an error.

```
ws_a.Range("D2:D" & LastRowCriar).Formula = "=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(IBAN!D:D,MATCH(B2&I2,IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E,0)),INDEX(IBAN!D:D,MATCH(B2&I2-1,IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E,0))),INDEX(IBAN!D:D,MATCH(B2&I2-2,IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E,0))),INDEX(IBAN!D:D,MATCH(B2&I2-3,IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E,0)))"
```

Once again, the formula works when hardcoded, I just need some help on how to use it in VBA. Probably, I have to declare those arrays but I am not sure (if I have to or how to do it).

Hardcoded:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(IBAN!D:D;MATCH(B2&I2;IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E;0));INDEX(IBAN!D:D;MATCH(B2&I2-1;IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E;0)));INDEX(IBAN!D:D;MATCH(B2&I2-2;IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E;0)));INDEX(IBAN!D:D;MATCH(B2&I2-3;IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E;0)))
```

Thank you!

Comment: show the hardcoded formula

Comment: Harcoded: =IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(IBAN!D:D;MATCH(B2&I2;IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E;0));INDEX(IBAN!D:D;MATCH(B2&I2-1;IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E;0)));INDEX(IBAN!D:D;MATCH(B2&I2-2;IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E;0)));INDEX(IBAN!D:D;MATCH(B2&I2-3;IBAN!F:F&IBAN!E:E;0)))

Comment: You will need to loop: `ws_a.Range("D2:D" & LastRowCriar)` and use `.FormulaArray` and change all the `2` to the correct row number inside the loop.

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding what you mean by "change all the `2` to the correct row number inside the loop", I am sorry. In a formula without the arrays, for instance `ws_a.Range("F2:F" & LastRowCriar).Formula = "=INDEX(IBAN!H:H,MATCH(D2,IBAN!D:D,0))"` I don't need the loop, it will perform from F2 to the LastRow of column F

Comment: The main issue is that it'd ecceed the formulaarray length limit of 255 chars: resolve to use named ranges to shorten the formula length. Then there's what already Scott Craner already pointed out

Comment: The formula has 229 chars. I am not understanding how would I create a loop in this specific formula. I am not sure if you are talking about a loop like from instance `from i=0 to i=10`

Comment: You are right, it exceeded 255 chars in my R1C1 translation… So your issue is the use of those semicolons (`;`) that must be turned into colon (`,`) for use in VBA formula. And what's in Scott's comment, too

Answer (score 0):

### Replace Slow Formula With VBA

With this setup, the code will write the resulting values to the 4th ("D") column (`cSh1C3`) in `Sheet1` named "Sheet1". The sheet name wasn't mentioned, so change it appropriately, Also change the other constants to fit your needs. Maybe change `cSh1C3` to an empty column first, to see if the code does the expected. There will be no formulas just the values since your formula is slowing down the worksheet considerably. If this code is doing the expected, then the formula isn't. In some cases the results differ, but I think the code is correct. When this happens, check the accuracy manually.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceSlowFormulaWithVBA()

    ' Sheet1
    Const cSh1 As String = "Sheet1"   ' Sheet1 Name
    Const cSh1FR As Long = 2          ' Sheet1 First Row Number
    Const cSh1C1 As Variant = 2 ' "B" ' Sheet1 First Column Number/Letter
    Const cSh1C2 As Variant = 9 ' "I" ' Sheet1 Second Column Number/Letter
    Const cSh1C3 As Variant = 4 ' "D" ' Target Column Number/Letter
                                      ' (Sheet1 Third Column Number/Letter)
    Const cReduce As Long = 3         ' Reduce Number

    ' Sheet2
    Const cSh2 As String = "IBAN"     ' Sheet2 Name
    Const cSh2FR As Long = 2          ' Sheet2 First Row Number
    Const cSh2C1 As Variant = 6 ' "F" ' Sheet2 First Column Number/Letter
    Const cSh2C2 As Variant = 5 ' "E" ' Sheet2 Second Column Number/Letter
    Const cSh2C3 As Variant = 4 ' "D" ' Source Column Number/Letter
                                      ' Sheet2 Third Column Number/Letter

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet              ' First Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet              ' Second Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range                  ' Various Ranges
    Dim vnt1 As Variant               ' Sheet1 Array
    Dim vnt1C1 As Variant             ' Sheet1 First Column Array
    Dim vnt1C2 As Variant             ' Sheet1 Second Column Array
    Dim vntT As Variant               ' Target Array (Sheet1 Third Column Array)
    Dim vnt2 As Variant               ' Sheet2 Array
    Dim vnt2C1 As Variant             ' Sheet2 First Column Array
    Dim vnt2C2 As Variant             ' Sheet2 Second Column Array
    Dim vntS As Variant               ' Source Array (Sheet2 Third Column Array)
    Dim LR As Long                    ' Last Row Compare Number
    Dim sh1LR As Long                 ' Sheet1 (Current) Last Row Number
    Dim sh2LR As Long                 ' Sheet2 (Current) Last Row Number
    Dim UB1 As Long                   ' Sheet1 Arrays Upper Bound
    Dim UB2 As Long                   ' Sheet2 Arrays Upper Bound
    Dim i As Long                     ' Various Counters
    Dim j As Long                     ' Second Array Elements Counter
    Dim k As Long                     ' Reduce Counter
    Dim lng1 As Long                  ' Current Sheet1 Array Value
    Dim lng2 As Long                  ' Current Sheet2 Array Value

    ' IN RANGES

    ' Define Worksheets.
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSh1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSh2)

    ' Calculate Sheet1 Last Row Number.
    Set rng = ws1.Columns(cSh1C1): GoSub LastRow: sh1LR = LR
    Set rng = ws1.Columns(cSh1C2): GoSub LastRow
    If LR > sh1LR Then sh1LR = LR

    ' Calculate Sheet2 Last Row Number.
    Set rng = ws2.Columns(cSh2C1): GoSub LastRow: sh2LR = LR
    Set rng = ws2.Columns(cSh2C2): GoSub LastRow
    If LR > sh2LR Then sh2LR = LR
    Set rng = ws2.Columns(cSh2C3): GoSub LastRow
    If LR > sh2LR Then sh2LR = LR

    ' Write Column Ranges to Arrays.
    vnt1C1 = ws1.Cells(cSh1FR, cSh1C1).Resize(sh1LR - cSh1FR + 1)
    vnt1C2 = ws1.Cells(cSh1FR, cSh1C2).Resize(sh1LR - cSh1FR + 1)
    vnt2C1 = ws2.Cells(cSh2FR, cSh2C1).Resize(sh2LR - cSh2FR + 1)
    vnt2C2 = ws2.Cells(cSh2FR, cSh2C2).Resize(sh2LR - cSh2FR + 1)
    vntS = ws2.Cells(cSh2FR, cSh2C3).Resize(sh2LR - cSh2FR + 1)

    ' Define Target Range.
    Set rng = ws1.Cells(cSh1FR, cSh1C3).Resize(sh1LR - cSh1FR + 1)

    ' Release worksheet object variables.
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing

    ' IN ARRAYS

    ' Define and populate Sheet1 Array from the two Sheet1 Column Arrays.
    UB1 = UBound(vnt1C1)
    ReDim vnt1(1 To UB1)          ' 1D 1-based (1-row)
    For i = 1 To UB1: vnt1(i) = vnt1C1(i, 1) & vnt1C2(i, 1): Debug.Print vnt1(i): Next i
    ' Erase the two Sheet1 Column Arrays.
    Erase vnt1C1: Erase vnt1C2
    ' Define and populate Sheet2 Array from the two Sheet2 Column Arrays.
    UB2 = UBound(vnt2C1)
    ReDim vnt2(1 To UB2)          ' 1D 1-based (1-row)
    For i = 1 To UB2: vnt2(i) = vnt2C1(i, 1) & vnt2C2(i, 1): Next i
    ' Erase the two Sheet2 Column Arrays.
    Erase vnt2C1: Erase vnt2C2
    ' Resize Target Array to rows defined by the number of elements
    ' in Sheet1 Array.
    ReDim vntT(1 To UB1, 1 To 1)  ' 2D 1-based 1-column

    ' Loop through elements of Sheet1 Array.
    For i = 1 To UB1
        If IsNumeric(vnt1(i)) Then
            ' Loop through Reduce Values.
            For k = 0 To cReduce
                ' Calculate Current Sheet1 Array Value.
                lng1 = vnt1(i) - k
                ' Loop through elements of Sheet2 Array.
                For j = 1 To UB2
                    If IsNumeric(vnt2(j)) Then
                        ' Calculate Current Sheet2 Array Value.
                        lng2 = vnt2(j)
                        ' Compare current Sheet1 and Sheet2 Array Values.
                        If lng1 = lng2 Then
                            ' Write value of current element (row) in Source
                            ' Array to current element (row) in Target Array.
                            vntT(i, 1) = vntS(j, 1)
                            ' Ensure exiting "For k"-loop immediately after
                            ' exiting "For j"-loop.
                            k = cReduce
                            ' Exit "For j"-loop.
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
            Next k
        End If
    Next i

    ' IN RANGES

    ' Write Target Array to Target Range.
    rng = vntT

Exit Sub

LastRow:
    LR = 0
    Set rng = rng.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then LR = rng.Row
Return

End Sub
```